# row wise action in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am in need to update a table with grade for each employee one by one, the table on jsp page shows some performance data of individual employee in each row along with a **struts2 select** drop down list in each row and a update **anchor tag**. Which is created using **struts2 iterator** tag.

What I need is while I press this update link it should take the selected value from dropdown list and update the current row.

How to achieve this ?  I want to know what do I need to do in onClick event for update anchor tag?

Comment: Do you want to do this with AJAX or just submit? What do you have so far?

Comment: I have nothing right now I stuck with this above mentioned question I want to know what do i need to do in onClick event for update anchor tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question. In this I generate **id** dynamically for input in each row of a column, mean while the anchor tag also generated with this element id respectively as a parameter for javascript function inside onclick attribute. So while I click update link it takes the textfield id of this corrosponding row to the javascript function. This makes me to get the value and update it row wise. Here is a example how I did it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function updateRole(roleID,targetID,id){

            var role = document.getElementById(roleID).value;
            var target = document.getElementById(targetID).value;
            $.ajax({
                url:"updateTeamemploydetails.action",
                data:"testRole="+role + "-" + target + "-" + id,
            }); 

</script>

<table>
            <tr>
                <th >S.No</th>
                <th >Name</th>
                <th >Role</th>
                <th >Target</th>
                <th >Action</th>
            </tr>
                <s:iterator value="emplist" status="empStatus">
            <tr>
                <td ><s:property value="#empStatus.count"/></td>
                <td ><s:property value="empname"/></td>
                <td ><s:textfield name="emprole" id="%{#empStatus.count}" theme="simple"/></td>
                <td ><s:textfield name="target" id="target%{#empStatus.count}" theme="simple"/></td>
                <td ><a href="#" onclick="updateRole('<s:property value="%{#empStatus.count}"/>','target'+'<s:property value="%{#empStatus.count}"/>','<s:property value="empid"/>');" >Update</a></td>
            </tr>
                </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

On `onclick` event call a javascript method. Inside method read all values and then send all these values to server.
You can do it using normal form post or Ajax as well.

Comment: how do I get the selected value to javascript or jquery. Its a big problem for me since it is inside a table and there are as many list as the rows are and with same name.

Comment: give attribute/column of each row a unique id. And then you can use id to read value. Now the table can grow dynamically so you need to find a generic way to attach unique id. This you can achieve while populating the table. One suggestion for id is like "attributeName"+count. You should increment count during show/populate. This way you will have a unique id for each row/column.

Comment: @rai.skumar: Your edit about appending rows with javascript is irrelevant. Question is NOT about that. I suggest you remove it from your answer.

Comment: @Sathish updated that he is not able to get values of selected row.. so i just wanted to explain that how can you make a row unique. Becoz unless each row has unique id you won't be able to get values. If its of no value then will take it off...